# Prove that $\rho(I - M^{-1}A)<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let we have real square matrices $M$ and $A$ such that $A = A^T$ and $(Mx, x) > \frac{1}{2} (Ax, x) > 0, \forall x \ne 0 $. Prove that $\rho(I - M^{-1}A)<1$ where $\rho(A)$ is spectral radius.

It should be somehow connected with Neumann series. I have no proof, just some details. For example $\rho(I - M^{-1}A)<1$ equivalent to $\rho(\frac{1}{2}M^{-1}A) < 1$. And if $\rho(\frac{1}{2}M^{-1}A) < 1$ than series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2}M^{-1}A)^n$ converges and equals $(I - \frac{1}{2}M^{-1}A)^{-1} = M(M - \frac{1}{2}A)^{-1}$, where $M$ and $M - \frac{1}{2}A$ are positive definite by the statement.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is positive definite, so it has a positive definite square root which I'll denote as $A^{1/2}$.  Now from $(M x, x) > \frac{1}{2} (Ax, x)$, writing $x = A^{-1/2} y$ we get $$(A^{-1/2} M A^{-1/2} y, y) > \frac{1}{2} (y, y)$$
That is for real vectors $y$, but for complex vectors $z$ we get
(using a sesquilinear inner product)
$$  \text{Re}\; (A^{-1/2} M A^{-1/2} z, z) > \frac{1}{2} (z, z)$$
In particular this implies that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^{-1/2} M A^{-1/2}$ has real part $> 1/2$.  The eigenvalues of $I - M^{-1} A$ are the same as those of $I - A^{1/2} M^{-1} A^{1/2}$, and these are $1 - 1/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1/2} M A^{-1/2}$.  The fractional linear transformation 
$\lambda \to 1 - 1/\lambda$ takes the half-plane $\text{Re}(\lambda) > 1/2$ to the interior of the unit circle.  Thus the spectral radius is indeed $< 1$.